# Qt calling QApplication::exec from library

Tags: c++, c, qt, user-interface

This is a follow on from a question I asked about embedding Qt code in a legacy C application.

I am able to build Qt code into my C application and was surprised to find that I can even run gui code from within the static library I'm using to do this. 
(My C application is also GUI driven, by the way).
This opens up some exciting possibilities, and I'm trying to get the two GUIs to work side by side.

The problem I have now is that in order to launch Qt GUI code I need to call QApplication::exec(), which is effectively blocking the rest of my application as it doesn't return until I kill the qt gui.

Is there any way I can start the qt gui code up and still return to my host application?

I appreciate I could start my Qt code up as a different process and implement some inter process communication, but the whole point is to try and get this embedded as a library.

There's also no way I can host the legacy application in Qt, before anyone suggests that!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I know this isn't helpful, but this is the kind of thing that may even work, you may even find a workaround but isn't really how you should do things. Properly porting your application to Qt is the answer. Or just keep doing it the legacy way if you can't port it.

Comment: you're right, that isn't helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your problem is threading.

Since you are doing C, *pthreads* is probably available to you.

```
void * qt_thread(void * parm) {
    // code here
    QApplication::exec();
} 

//some where in your main()
pthread_t qt;
pthread_create(&qt, NULL, qt_thread, NULL); //returns immediately
// rest of code
```

This is a VERY rough example, you should study and learn threading properly.

Good reference:
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: Doesn't the existence of two event loops (on from Qt, other from the legacy GUI) creates a few problems? Like a modal window launched from a given loop doesn't block the other.

Comment: @VitorBraga that's an interesting point, I'd have to do some research on that.

Comment: If you look around SO you're going to find people who extended legacy applications (MFC, Motif) with Qt plugins and then stumbled on problems like this - and there's no clean solution, I believe. Trolltech used to offer (I don't know if Nokia still does) the MFC migration solution because of problems like this. I suffered enough porting legacy applications to Qt :~ I wish others a better fate!

Comment: thanks chaps. I had thought of the event loop issue but that was my next worry!

Comment: QApplication::exec() have to be called from main thread. That simply don't work with at least Qt5.*

Answer (score 5):

Don't call QApplication::exec(). Instead have the application call QApplication::processEvents() in it's event loop.

Comment: This is better than the thread option. I'm curious to see how well this performs in practice.

Comment: i'll report back when I've given it a go. It certainly looks like the better option.

Comment: Follow up to this - it's very easy to start a seperate thread and call QApplication::exec inside the thread. e.g:

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can start a second thread (e.g., using the pthread library) and start QApplication::exec() from the second thread. However, you must be very careful when communicating with your QT code in order not to have race conditions in your library.